# Modal Presentation Forcing Navigation Controller to Pop to Root

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am having a strange problem that I can't seem to find the cause for.

When attempting to present a modal view controller on a navigation controller the navigation controller is popping all of my view controllers underneath when the modal is dismissed.

So after pushing a few view controllers and presenting a modal on the topViewController, I end up back at the rootViewController when the modal is dismissed.

Anyone had this happen to them lately, I can't seem to find the reasoning for why this is happening?

Comment: how do you present/dismiss the Modal ViewController?

Comment: the usual [self presentViewController] from navigationController's topViewController and [self dismissViewController] from the modal

Comment: it is very wired, can you add your code as i think there should be something else which cause this problem

Comment: I'm actually having the same issue. I've uploaded a quick demo project to github: [Demo Project](https://github.com/engineeringman/navigationcontrollerbug) The reason I created a child controller is for autolayout constraint convenience. After loading the project, I need to be able to swap out different view controllers. I reported the bug to apple 2 weeks ago, and still haven't received a response :/

Comment: @Jangles have you solved the issue? I seem to have the same thing going on.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for @rshev:

It was actually a user error.  Here's what was happening: I had a view controller with a manually added navigationController on top of it (as a subview/child VC).  The nav controller then had 3 VCs in its stack.  The third (and visible) VC was presenting an image picker controller.  When the image picker was dismissed, I momentarily saw my third VC , then it quickly popped back to the 1st, discarding the other two VC's from memory.

So what went wrong?  What I didn't realize is that `viewDidAppear` (and `viewWillAppear`) was being called on my content view controller (the one with nav controller for its subview).  This content VC was actually setting its navigation controller (and adding it as a subview) on viewDidAppear, thus covering up the original nav controller.

To solve it, I just added a static boolean to determine when the first VC FIRST appears, like so:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    static BOOL firstAppearance = YES;

    if (firstAppearance)
    {
        firstAppearance = NO;

        UINavigationController *navController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavigationController"];
        [navController.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];

        [self.view addSubview:navController.view];

        [self addChildViewController:navController];

        [navController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.